# Polymorphism: Accessing inherited class variable

Tags: c++

I have a class that is inherited from an abstract base class.

```
class CStateBase
{
  friend class CApplication;
  friend class CGraphics;
  virtual int Update() =0;
};

class CStateTitle: private CStateBase
{
  friend class CApplication;
  friend class CGraphics;
  CApplication *f_App;

  int m_iR;

  int Update();

  CStateTitle(CApplication *App);
  ~CStateTitle();
};
```

In a method of another class, CStateTitle is dynamically allocated into a CStateBase pointer. However, if I use that pointer to try and access the variable int m_iR, the compiler looks for the variable in CStateBase and therefore makes an error. If I could declare virtual int m_iR in the base class I would think it would work fine, but for some reason it's not letting me declare virtual data members. What is the recommended way to get around this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You most likely want a virtual destructor in your base class, see e.g. Sutters [Virtuality](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Comment: In what way does an ordinary non-virtual member variable not solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to abstract the access of `m_iR` into some virtual function.

Another choice would be to move `m_iR` from `CStateTitle` into `CStateBase`.  This only makes sense if every class needs an `m_iR`.

A last resort would be to do a dynamic cast:

```
CStateBase *csb = ...;

CStateTitle *cst = dynamic_cast<CStateTitle *>(csb);
if (cst)
{
    // have a valid CStateTitle
}
else
{
    // csb is not pointing at a CStateTitle, do whatever is appropriate
}
```

Comment: Your final idea is perfectly valid, but should be avoided if possible. It's a red flag that says you didn't put enough thought into your polymorphism.

Comment: @MarkRandom - I agree with you which is why I put that option last.  I've changed my wording to "last resort" to emphasize that.

Answer (score 5):

You should inherit publicly from the base class:

```
class CStateTitle: public CStateBase
```

otherwise `CStateTitle` *is not a* `CStateBase` from the compiler's point of view, thus you can't polymorphically access `CStateTitle` objects via a `CStateBase` pointer.

You can't have virtual data members, only virtual methods in C++. So a workaround could be to declare virtual accessor method(s) for your data member.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to access a derived class's member directly from a base class pointer, you are obviously not invoking polymorphism.  Therefore you can use `dynamic_cast` to access that member.

Unsolicited advice:  Don't access member variables directly.  Think about your hierarchy and how the operation you're trying to accomplish can be accessed using some kind of consistent interface using a virtual method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have virtual member variables.

You can change when you cast:

```
CStateTitle *a = new CStateTitle();
a->m_iR = 1;
CStateBase *b = a;
```

or re cast sometime later using RTTI

```
CStateBase *a = new CStateTitle();
CStateTitle *b = dynamic_cast<CStateTitle*>(a);
if( NULL != b )
  b->m_iR = 1;
```

or add a virtual setter method on the base class if all CStateBase where going to have some int that needed to be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define a virtual function in the base class to perform the required acccess (getter and/or setter), or, you will have to cast your base pointer to a derived* and continue from there.